# Is there a scale at which all solids can be treated as fluids?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, solid-mechanics

I was answering [an Earth Science SE question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/18815/centripetal-force-perfect-ball-and-water) that involved the reasons why Earth has an equatorial bulge, and wanted to make an offhand comment such as *"Real planetary constituents aren't this strong; at the scale of the Earth everything can be treated as a fluid"*. Then I realized that a reality check was in order.

Most solids have some level of deformability. Even extremely hard materials can fracture, and when there are enough pieces they'll act as a fluid. One thinks of sand dunes in a desert, and the moon [Miranda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miranda_(moon)), which appears to be a rubble pile whose gravity pulled it into a spherical shape.

Nathaniel, in his answer to [this other Physics SE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60508/equivalence-of-turbulence-in-solid-materials/60513), said

> The trouble is that to the extent that solids can be treated as fluids, they're fluids with really, really high viscosities.

My guess is, you can overcome viscosity by increasing the forces involved (for example, getting enough matter together in one place) and/or the time scale.

One thing that gives me pause is the myth that window glass "flows like a liquid" if left long enough -- any apparent effect like this is just an artifact of how glass used to be manufactured and set in windows. But that's just a really small scale.

So, is there a scale at which all solids can be treated as fluids, and how big do you have to get?

Comment: The way crystals deform is by motion of dislocations. If there are no dislocations, you can wait forever - they won't deform.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey So a perfect quartz crystal the mass of the Earth....

Comment: Practically speaking perfect crystals are unstable due to gravity-induced stress at large enough scales, not to mention other things like thermal gradients. Think about how brittle a silicon wafer is due to its size. I would basically discount single crystals from discussions about the behavior objects larger than 10 centimeters except in theoretical circumstances.

Comment: @KFGauss OK, so I think that means Mike Dunlavey's objecion doesn't hold up on a large enough scale.

Comment: I think the centrifugal force causes strain in the body, increasing the radius at the equator. So the value of centrifugal force and bulk modulus of the solid will determine if the change in radius will be significant. This wouldn't need you to assume a solid as a viscous fluid.